# how to filter Postgresql jsonb like query key inside key

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id        data
0a        {"name" : "x1", "source_extended_attributes": {"alexa_pageviews": 6000}}
7ee       {"name" : "x2", "source_extended_attributes": {"alexa_pageviews": 6000}}
8d        {"name" : "x3", "source_extended_attributes": {"alexa_pageviews": 6000}}
```

The `data` column is defined as jsonb.

I need to use a select where `alexa_pageviews` but I can't.

I can use `name` like `where data->>'name' = 'x1'`

i need how access key inside key in PostgreSQL query

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for? All rows that contain the key `alexa_pageviews`? Or all rows where the value for that key has a specific value?

Comment: Are you looking for `data -> 'source_extended_attributes' ->> 'alexa_pageviews'`

Comment: all rows where the value for that key has a specific value for example where `alexa_pageviews` > 6000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: `data->'source_extended_attributes'->>'alexa_pageviews'`
If you want to compare the value with something, there are several ways.

As text (returns JSON value as text explicitly using `->>` operator):

```
data->'source_extended_attributes'->>'alexa_pageviews' like '6%'
```

As numeric (casts the TEXT representation to the NUMERIC value to the given type (`int`)):

```
(data->'source_extended_attributes'->>'alexa_pageviews')::int > 5000
```

As JSON numeric (implicitly casts righthand TEXT constant to JSON type):

```
data->'source_extended_attributes'->'alexa_pageviews' > '999'
```